# Cant get $_POST[] values if form class="contact-form"

Tags: php, html, forms, post

I have been trying to figure out why `$_POST` would not catch any input fields in my html contact form.

I sorted it out after many hours and I came to the conclusion that it was because of my `form` having a `class` of `"contact-form"`

Example this **will** work:

```
<form id="main-contact-form" name="contact-form" method="post" action="sendemail.php" role="form">                          
   <input type="text" name="name" class="form-control" required="required" placeholder="Name">                                    
</form>
```

output: `$_POST['name']; // This successfully catch the value`

this **wont**:`

```
<form id="main-contact-form" class="contact-form" name="contact-form" method="post" action="sendemail.php" role="form">                          
   <input type="text" name="name" class="form-control" required="required" placeholder="Name">                                    
</form>
```

output: `$_POST['name']; // This doesnot catch the value`

JS:

```
var form = $('.contact-form');
form.submit(function () {
    $this = $(this);
    $.post($(this).attr('action'), function(data) {
        $this.prev().text(data.message).fadeIn().delay(3000).fadeOut();
    },'json');
    return false;
});
```

Why is this?

Comment: Are there any javascripts in your file?

Comment: Do you have javascript code that is binding to `.contact-form`?

Comment: This is a clientside issue. How do you submit? With payload data? Check the posted values in your network tab (developer bar)

Comment: I just edited my post forgot to put js in

Comment: In your `$.post()` you are not posting any data, so its no wonder why `$_POST['name'];` is empty.

Comment: From the manual [`jQuery.post( url [, data ] [, success ] [, dataType ] )`](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.post/), you need to do something like `$.post($(this).attr('action'), $(this).serialize(), function(data) { ...[rest of your code]... },'json');`

Answer (score 0):

Replace your js snippet with this:

```
<script>
var form = $('.contact-form');
form.submit(function () {
    $this = $(this);
    $.post($(this).attr('action'),{ name: $('input[name=name]').val() }, function(data) {
        $this.prev().text(data.message).fadeIn().delay(3000).fadeOut();
    },'json');
    return false;
});
</script>
```

You need to specify the passing parameters!

You can use this:

```
$.post($(this).attr('action'),$(this).serialize(), function(data) {...
```

to post all the form controls.